# How does the .match method work in relation to its args?

Tags: ruby, methods, arguments

I am learning how to program in Ruby through the website RubyMonk.com (Fantastic website from what I know so far).

I am having a bit of trouble understanding the concept of RegEx and how it works with the .match method.

```
'RubyMonk Is Pretty Brilliant'.match(/ ./, 9)
```

What are the use(s) of the arguments in .match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optional parameter of the [`String#match`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-match) is to specify the starting position from where search begin:

```
'RubyMonk Is Pretty Brilliant'.match(/ ./, 0)
# => #<MatchData " I">
'RubyMonk Is Pretty Brilliant'.match(/ ./, 9)
# => #<MatchData " P">
'RubyMonk Is Pretty Brilliant'.match(/ ./, 12)
# => #<MatchData " B">
```

Answer (score 0):

> What are the use(s) of the arguments in .match?

Read the documentation of [`String#match`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-match)

> Converts pattern to a Regexp (if it isn’t already one), then invokes its match method on str. *If the **second parameter** is present, it specifies the position in the string to begin the search.*

Thus in your example, `#match` will start its work from **10<sup>th</sup>** character or **9<sup>th</sup>** position on-wards.